# React making AJAX request in render without onClick trigger

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have started yesterday to teach myself some React. I have a login form that is supposed to send a AJAX request to my backend when a button is clicked. This works, when I have my backend not running, meaning: My self written backend (tested with postman) has to be turned off so it does not reply and the page can render. 
When it is running though the method gets called on render which is absolutely not desired as my backend sends an error and the page does not render.

My react code is here:

The Constructor:

```
constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.login                = this.login.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeUser     = this.handleChangeUser.bind(this);
        this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            user:     '',
            password: '',
            loggedIn: props.loggedIn
        };
    }
```

The Form:

```
return (
                <div>
                    <Navigation/>
                    <div style={{position: "relative", left: "30%", right: "70%"}}>
                        <label>Username</label><br/>
                        <input type={'text'} onChange={this.handleChangeUser} style={{width: "300px"}}/><br/>
                        <label>Password</label><br/>
                        <input type={'password'} onChange={this.handleChangePassword} style={{width: "300px"}}/><br/>
                        <div style={{width: "300px"}}>
                            <button type={"button"} className={"btn btn-primary"} style={{marginTop: "10px"}} onClick={this.login}>
                                Login
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
```

And the login function that is causing all the trouble:

```
login(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url:    BASE_URL + LOGIN,
            data:   {
                user:     this.state.user,
                password: this.state.password
            }
        }).then(function (result)
        {
            localStorage.setItem('botusToken', result.body.token);
            this.setState({loggedIn: true});
        }).catch(function ()
        {
            console.log("Error while login in");
        });
    }
```

This example works like a charm:

```
render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <label htmlFor="comment">Some comment</label>
                    <label htmlFor="triggerWord">Which trigger-word would you like your tweet to belong to?</label>
                    <select className={"form-control"} onChange={this.handleChangeSelector}>
                        <option>Sad</option>
                        <option>Fake News</option>
                        <option>Taxes</option>
                        <option>Immigrants</option>
                        <option>Make America Great Again</option>
                        <option>Make a new trigger word</option>
                    </select>
                    <Textarea className={"form-control"} rows={2} cols={50} maxLength={140} wrap={"soft"}
                              onChange={this.handleChangeTextArea} value={this.state.tweet}/>
                </form>
                <br/>
                <button type={"button"} className={"btn btn-primary"} onClick={this.submitTweet}>Submit</button>
                <div style={errStyle}>{this.state.err}</div>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

This method works like a charm in harmony with the form above:

```
submitTweet(e)
    {
        let self = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        let isNew = false;
        if (this.state.topic === "Make a new trigger word") isNew = true;
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url:    BASE_URL + SUBMIT_TWEET,
            data:   {
                topic: this.state.topic,
                tweet: this.state.tweet,
                new:   isNew
            }
        }).then(function ()
        {
            self.setState({err: ''});
        }).catch(function (err)
        {
            self.setState({err: "You have not entered all necessary information!"});
        });

        this.setState({tweet: ''});

    };
```

Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Shouldn't you be `POST`ing rather than `GET`ing if you're submitting a form?

Comment: //when I have my backend not running// can u explain this statement. Also share your full code...you need to define button type="button"

Comment: Post error message if any

Comment: @hawk There is non. Only my server reply get rendered on the screen

Comment: @Timbo Make sure your ajax method is called, put breakpoint or console.log

Comment: It is not called anymore! I have another form where it works. Will post above

Comment: @Timbo check your console for any error.. btw button type must be `button`

Comment: @hawk Console is really empty. No error is thrown. I changed it to type button

Comment: Please do not ask me why, but it works now after restarting the backend (no changes where made)

Answer (score 1):

How about changing `onClick={() => this.login}` to `onClick={(e) => this.login(e)}`

The this.login was getting called on render. That's why the render was working on when the backend was not running.

To bind a function in a React class either use the bind call in the constructor or the arrow function in the tag.

Comment: Give me a moment I don't know what is going on. I have to change the question. It renders now but the onClick is not triggered

Comment: How it should help?

Comment: Can you remove the bind code for the login function from the constructor? comment this line and let me know if it runs. `this.login                = this.login.bind(this);`

Comment: @palsrealm Yes that runs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `onClick={() => this.login}` just do `onClick={this.login}`

Comment: I had that before this does not work either, or now it works again but the onClick is not triggered